# Converting protobuf to bigquery in Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow

We use protobuf with GCP's pubsub and dataflow. We define both data we send to pubsub as well as bigquery schema with a single proto file.

publisher -(send proto)-> pubsub -> dataflow -(write)-> bigquery

Sometime dataflow does some cosmetic changes but it's mostly copying fields from protobuf to bigquery.

My question is that, is there a way to automatically convert protobuf model to bigquery's TableRow?

Simplified dataflow code we have now is below. I want to eliminate most of code in `ProtoToTableRow` class :

```
public class MyPipeline {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        events = pipeline.apply("ReadEvents",
                PubsubIO.readProtos(Core.MyProtoObject.class).fromSubscription(subscription));
        events.apply("ConvertToTableRows", ParDo.of(new ProtoToTableRow()))
                .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                        .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                        .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                        .to(table));
    }
}

// I want this class to be super thin!
class ProtoToTableRow extends DoFn<Core.MyProtoObject, TableRow> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Core.Foo foo = c.element().getFoo();
        TableRow fooRow = new TableRow()
                .set("id", foo.getId())
                .set("bar", foo.getBar())
                .set("baz", foo.getBaz());

        // similar code repeated for 100s of lines

        TableRow row = new TableRow()
                .set("foo", foo)

        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in a very cool way. Beam provides a schema inference methods for various classes including Java Beans, AutoValue classes, and also Protocol Buffers.

For your pipeline, you would not need to convert to TableRow, you could do something like this:

```
pipeline.getSchemaRegistry().registerSchemaProvider(
    Core.MyProtoObject.class, new ProtoMessageSchema());

events = pipeline.apply("ReadEvents",
                PubsubIO.readProtos(Core.MyProtoObject.class).fromSubscription(subscription));

events.apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.<Core.MyProtoObject>write()
                        . useBeamSchema()
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                        .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                        .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                        .to(table));
```

Note the `useBeamSchema`  argument in `BigQueryIO.write` - this will use the automatic conversion.

Comment: Note the protobuf schema provider isn't part of core beam, its part of beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf

Comment: it seems useBeamRows does not exist so I needed to change it to useBeamSchema. After that I got type error "reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PCollection<Transaction> conforms to PCollection<Object>" (transaction is name of my proto). Any ideas?

Comment: Answering my own question - I needed to provide type info to BigQuery.write like BigQuery.<Transaction>write. I'll edit answer

Comment: Hmm actually it's still not working. Now I get runtime error from this line checkArgument(input.hasSchema()); even though I think I provide schema via pipeline.getSchemaRegistry().registerSchemaProvider(
    Core.MyProtoObject.class, new ProtoMessageSchema());

Answer (score 1):

**datahem** team using *protobuf* annotations to create dynamic BigQury schmea

https://github.com/mhlabs/datahem.processor/tree/master/generic/src/main/java/org/datahem/processor/generic

Refer:https://robertsahlin.com/schema-evolution-in-streaming-dataflow-jobs-and-bigquery-tables-part-1/